# Vuetify icons show as italic texts

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I just started a new vue2 project with vuetify, added a few components, navbar and so on.

[image]

I don't know why my icon showed as italic texts.

I don't see any **errors** on the console, or network tab.

Does anyone know how can I fix it ?

Do I need to add anything to src/main.js ?

---

## I've tried

**src/plugins/vuetify.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib/framework'

Vue.use(Vuetify)

export default new Vuetify({
    icons: {
        iconfont: 'mdi' // 'mdi' || 'mdiSvg' || 'md' || 'fa' || 'fa4' || 'faSvg'
    }
})
```

Comment: looks like you are using `class="font-italic"` ?

Comment: Are you applying the `mdi-` prefix? Like `mdi-home`. That usually happens when can't find the icon.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the default icon font for Vuetify. You can include it through a CDN:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@6.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Or as a local dependency:

```
$ yarn add @mdi/font -D

// OR

$ npm install @mdi/font -D
```